# All-in-one linux messenger

Tags: linux, chat, desktop-client

The question: **What's your preferred linux application that centralizes the major chat applications (WhatsApp, Telegram, Signal, etc.) into one?**

#### Further details

*What kind of application are you looking for?*

A desktop linux application that centralizes other messaging applications. It's purpose is to reduce the number of applications needed to communication with people across platforms. The user problem is, "as a user, I want one app to use for messaging people so that I don't have to download, configure, update, keep track of notifications, etc. for multiple messaging apps".

*What operating system do you want the application to run on?*

The application should run on desktop Ubuntu. I found Beeper (https://www.beeper.com/) but this application isn't yet released.

*What budget do you have?*

The app should be $10 or less per month.

*What features must the application have?*

1. Able to send and receive messages from WhatsApp
2. Ditto for Signal
3. Ditto for Telegram
4. Ditto for Facebook Messenger
5. Ditto for Instagram

Comment: So you search for particular software or you want to collect others experience?

Comment: What Romeo points at is: [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) ;)

Comment: There are multiple apps like that, but I don't think any of them supports Signal.

Comment: @Izzy I edited the question to answer the questions listed at the link you provided.